# How to uninstall unity webapps feature?

Tags: update-manager, webapps

**I think the servers were not working and that was the origin of the problem**

I am running 12.04 and installed the Unity Webapps thing. I didn't like the result and want to uninstall it but... I can't. It also broke Adobe Air because it messed up with the 32bit libraries (needed for Air to run).

I used

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webapps/preview
```

As it's explained in the ppa but I get thousands of errors:

```
W: Imposible obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-es  No se pudo conectar a es.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Imposible obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  No se pudo conectar a es.archive.ubuntu.com:http:

E: Algunos archivos de índice fallaron al descargar. Se han ignorado, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
PPA to be removed: webapps preview
comm: el fichero 2 no está ordenado
Package revert list generated:
 account-plugin-facebook/precise account-plugin-flickr/precise 
account-plugin-foursquare/precise account-plugin-google/precise 
account-plugin-identica/precise account-plugin-twitter/precise 
bamfdaemon/precise chromium-browser/precise chromium-browser-l10n/precise 
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg/precise indicator-appmenu/precise 
indicator-messages/precise indicator-status-provider-mc5/precise 
indicator-status-provider-pidgin/precise libaccount-plugin-1.0-0/precise 
libaccounts-glib0/precise libaccounts-qt1/precise libbamf0/precise 
libbamf3-0/precise libgwibber3/precise libgwibber-gtk3/precise 
libindicator-messages-status-provider1/precise libsignon-extension1/precise 
libsignon-glib1/precise libsignon-plugins-common1/precise libsignon-qt1/precise 
libufe-xidgetter0/precise libunity-core-5.0-5/precise libunity-webapps0/precise 
python-flickr-api/precise shotwell/precise signond/precise unity/precise 
unity-common/precise unity-services/precise unity-webapps/precise 
xul-ext-websites-integration/precise
```

And then this:

```
    E: No se encontró la Distribución «precise» para «libufe-xidgetter0»
E: No se encontró la Distribución «precise» para «libunity-webapps0»
E: No se encontró la Distribución «precise» para «python-flickr-api»
E: No se encontró la Distribución «precise» para «signond»
E: No se encontró la Distribución «precise» para «unity-webapps»
E: No se encontró la Distribución «precise» para «xul-ext-websites-integration»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «account-plugin-facebook»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «account-plugin-flickr»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «account-plugin-foursquare»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «account-plugin-google»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «account-plugin-identica»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «account-plugin-twitter»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «libaccount-plugin-1.0-0»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «libaccounts-glib0»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «libaccounts-qt1»
Incapaz de encontrar un archivo «precise» para el paquete «libgwibber3»
```

Now I can't update nor fix the Adobe Air problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uninstall WebApps with these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webapps/preview
```

As for the 32-bit libraries, you could try running this:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Which upgrades all existing packages and installs/updates all dependencies for existing packages as well.  I can't promise this will fix your issue with the 32-bit libraries, but it certainly won't hurt and it has the potential help.

Comment: It seems that my problem was actually related with the servers, so I mark your answer as valid because, at the end, it's the way to uninstall (if the servers are ok :P).